# Simple laravel html form

Tags: laravel

How write this code in simple html form in laravel blade

```
{!! Form::model($user, [
          'method' => 'PUT',
          'url'  => '/edit-account'    
]) !!}
```

In controller have this method:

```
public function edit(Request $request)
{
    $user = $request->user();
    return view('backend.home.edit', compact('user'));
}
```

Comment: I don't think i understand?
It's just HTML, so, <form method="post" action"/edit-account"> </form>

Comment: I think you pass hidden field with $user like <input type="hidden" value="{{$user}}" name="user[]">

Comment: Have you actually tried writing a “simple HTML form”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form method="post" action="/edit-account">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
</form>
```

**Explanation**

"method" in laravel collective form is similar to "method" attribute of html form.
"url" in laravel collective form is "action" attribute of html form.

As there are no put, patch and delete method we need to pass a hidden field named "_method" with value of "PUT" for updating data.

And anytime while defining HTML form in the application, we should include a hidden CSRF token field in the form so that the CSRF protection middleware can validate the request and here I am using csrf_field helper to generate the token field.

Comment: You might want to explain why for a better answer.

Comment: get this error Class App\Http\Requests does not exist, i have App\Http\Requests

Comment: I think that `App\Http\Requests` is actually a namespace.
So instead of using `App\Http\Requests`. You should use for your requests `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a form with a specific method you can do something like this :

```
<form action="/edit-account" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
    [... Inputs like <input type="email" name="email" value="old('email')/> ...]
</form>
```

or

```
<form action="/edit-account" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('PUT') }}
    [... Inputs like <input type="email" name="email" value="old('email')/> ...]
</form>
```

### Documentation

- [method_field()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-method-field)
- [csrf_field()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-csrf-field)
- [csrf_token()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-csrf-token)
- [old()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-old)

And if you want to see how to validate your form after submit: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation

Answer (score 0):

`Form::model` basically populates the input fields with data either from old input or given model's attributes. So the basic form can be written like this.

```
<form action="/edit-account" method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">

    ...

</form>
```

And for populating the data, you can use `old` helper function and then check for errors.

So a basic input block would look like this.

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name', $user->name) }}">

@if ($errors->has('name'))
    <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
@endif
```

#### References:

[`old()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-old)

[`csrf_token()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-csrf-token)

[Working With Error Messages](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#working-with-error-messages)